# Does the element have a child with a specific class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ag-grid-angular

I have the following problem. I have a table. In this table I know which cells are processed or invalid. However, I do not know for the row in the table. Now I want to set a mark at the beginning, whether a row was edited or not. this can be a before element on the row or a mark in the first cell. I'm new to a bigger project and I just can not figure out how to give a row a class and hope that it works without it. It is used Ag Grid and Angular.

I have already tried to see if I get along with sibling elements or if there are any pseudo-classes. Unfortunately, there is not yet has (). I can do it if it works on Chrome. Honestly, I'm a little bit desperate.

```
<div class = "ag-row">
<div class = "ag-cell edited-cell"> Content </ div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the JS code you have where you "know which cells are processed"?

Comment: Also thank you for the quick reaction. To be honest, I have been looking for it for some time. If I found out, I'll get in touch. I joined in an advanced state of the project. Also, I lack a bit of experience, but I get that already :).

Comment: "However, I do not know for the row in the table." Sure you do. If you know that a cell has been processed or is invalid, then immediately its row has also been processed or is invalid (unless you have some more complex logic which determines this for rows). Do you have trouble selecting the row for a cell?